# How to repeat text fields when I hit the submit button in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a fitness app using swift 3.
What I am trying to do is to have a text field where the user enters the exercise then under that another three text fields (one for the sets, reps, and weight). When the user clicks the "Add exercise button" underneath it repeats these text fields so the user can fill in the next exercise and so on.
How do I get the four text fields to pop up again after the user presses the "Add exercise button?
Thanks

Comment: You can achieve this with tableview. Whenever "Add Exercise button" is tapped increase number of rows by one and reload table view. Thought I am not sure how would you want your UI.

Comment: Another advantage of using UITableView/UITableViewController here is it will take care of adjusting UI according to Keyboard Up and Down when user types in UITextField

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response. I want to have a text field on the top left which is where the user will enter the exercise. Under this line is another three text fields in a row where the user will enter the reps, weight, and sets. Under this is the add exercise button. Is this possible to do using a table view as I cant see how that can be done? If so can you put me in the right direction how i can perform this layout? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make Simple TableList. when hit Submit button just increase Field List Count . TableList has only cell in start .

```
     func addNewField(){
         FieldListCount = FieldListCount + 1 
         tableView.reloadData 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `UICollectionView` and add *footer* to `collectionView`. For example:

Create a `collectionView`, each `cell` in `collectionView` has some `textFields`. And `footer` of this `collectionView` has a button *"Add new exercise"*.

When `button` is tapped, add new `cell` to `collectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

Preferred Solution :

1. User Custom Text Field view and on the press of submit button, after that add that TextField View into UIScrollView with increment in Y position. If use tableList some textField will not be created(not in memory) until the user will scroll the table list.